# How to write date / timestamp string to Date timestamp column in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, avro

I have stored some Oracle tables in Hadoop using AVRO file format and Hive external tables to access the data.
I have stored Date and Timestamp values as a formatted String, using the `TO_CHAR` function from Oracle on the import.

Now I want to export this exact data back with Spark to an Oracle table having a Date column. I use the command:

```
// Create a data frame from the Hive table
val data = sqlContext.sql("select * from avro_table")

// export df to existing oracle table
data.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(jdbcString, "tableName", prop)
```

But then i get the error:

> ORA-00902: invalid data type

This is because it tries to insert a string into a date column. Is there a safe way to insert a date / timestamp string from a Spark dataframe to an Oracle date / timestamp column? With safe i mean do not lose any timezone information.

Comment: Can you include `data.printSchema` and the format of the date column in Oracle in your question to make it complete and so the answers could get "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [to_date](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_date(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), [to_timestamp](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and/or [date_format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@date_format(dateExpr:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,format:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) functions to do the transformation from *stringified* date/timestamp values to their corresponding type-aware ones.

> **date_format(dateExpr: Column, format: String): Column** Converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of string in the format specified by the date format given by the second argument.
>
> **to_date(e: Column, fmt: String): Column** Converts the column into a DateType with a specified format (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) return null if fail.
>
> **to_timestamp(s: Column, fmt: String): Column** Convert time string to a Unix timestamp (in seconds) with a specified format (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) to Unix timestamp (in seconds), return null if fail.

Use `select` or `withColumn` operators.

A sample code could be as follows:

```
data.withColumn("real_date", date_format(...))
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .jdbc(jdbcString, "tableName", prop)
```

Comment: Any suggestion how to fix this ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020103/how-to-pass-date-timestamp-as-lowerbound-upperbound-in-spark-sql-2-4-1v-with-ojd